# NSUserDefaults in App Not Updating View in iPhone Settings App

Tags: iphone, application-settings

When I change and synchronize value in my app, they get saved, but the changes do not appear in the settings app. Is there a way to get them synced while maintaining the ability to make changes inside the app? Here is my code:

```
//I'm registering the defaults from the Settings bundle I created using David Keegan's class inside my application delegate
+ (void)initialize{
    if([self class] == [VirtualVeloAppDelegate class]){
        [InAppSettings registerDefaults];
    }
}

//I'm accessing the values like so
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud boolForKey:@"_someKey"]

//I'm setting the values like so
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switch.isOn forKey:@"_someKey"];

//After I'm done I sync
[ud synchronize];
```

The values are getting saved and recalled accurately in my application both on the iPad and iPhone. However they are not updating the Settings app.

I think the fact that I've found no clear cut explanation of this likely indicates Settings.bundle parameters can only be modified in the Settings app.

Comment: How are you (1) fetching and (2) saving changes? Please post your code.

Comment: Added code to shed light on the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was using Keegan3d's InAppSettings code in my app and it wasn't working, I used a fresh download of that project without any modifications and it worked. So if implemented correctly, the code from [this project](http://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home) works. I'm not sure where I had gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the settings should be updated if you update from your app. 
Check if you modify in Settings app, do you get modified value in your app?
Check if you are registering the defaults properly.
As you said iPad you must be using 3.2.x beta i guess.. Check if the beta don't have an issue.

Comment: I am registering the defaults properly and changes made in the Settings app can be recognized in the app, just not the other way around.